# How to change cast of elasticsearch field in scripted metric from Long to Double?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, casting

In my aggregators for an Elasticsearch query, I am trying to use a field that happens to be cast as type long, called `my_field` for this example:

```
"test-metric": {
    "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "_agg['test'] = []",
        "map_script": "_agg['test'].add(doc.['my_field'].value));
    }
}
```

In some instances, it so happens that 'my_field' actually contains a double value, such as `1.5`. When outputting the actual hits, I can see that `1.5` is being output.

My expectation would be that `_agg['test']` will contain that same value of `1.5`. However, it is immediately being cast as type `org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Longs` and all calculations thereafter are wrong.

I have tried modifying the schema and that appears to "fix" this, however in my current setup, it is not a viable solution to modify the schema for every instance where this comes up.

Instead, I am looking for a solution that will give me consistent values in the scripted metrics as what I am getting from the matched hits.

I have tried casting like this:

```
(org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Doubles) doc.get('averageSessionsPerWeek')
```

But, I get this error:

```
GroovyScriptExecutionException[GroovyCastException[Cannot cast object '[2]' with class 'org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Longs' to class 'org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Doubles' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Doubles(java.lang.Long)]];
```

It seems like the cast is applied at the time that the `doc` object is created.

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the mapping of that `my_field` field?

Comment: @AndreiStefan It is of type Long. We cannot easily control the type, however we recognize that it might be the only way. Still, I am asking on here to see if there is a way to do it.

Comment: What ES version? With 2.3 if you try to index `1.5` into a `long` field ES will throw an exception. Not tested, but I think it's the same in 1.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference `doc.['my_field'].value`: like you're doing here, you are accessing the doc values, which are the values stored in the reverse index in Elasticsearch. Because this field is mapped as a long (integer) instead of a floating point number, it is actually an integer value in the Elasticsearch index.

> When outputting the actual hits, I can see that 1.5 is being output.

When you examine the hits, you are looking at the Fielddata for that document, which is the json object (stored as a string) that you indexed into Elasticsearch. This still contains the exact json string that you indexed, and does not show any coercion from this initial value into what was indexed in the doc values.

This is easiest to understand when you think of an analyzed string field in Elasticsearch.

`{
   "sentence": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
}`

In the Fielddata, this would still be the string `"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"`, but in the reverse index in Elasticsearch it would be stored as the individual tokens:

`brown,
dog,
fox,
jump,
lazy,
over,
quick`

(actual index values would be different depending on analyzer used)

As far as the doc values (the reverse index) is concerned, your original value isn't even there.

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to understand what is happening and give this excellent explanation. I see that the only way to do this is to make sure that I have the correct types for the fields, but I really appreciate your explanation as to why I otherwise still get "1.5" output from the field.